# Cassandra bulk data writing in two node ring fails

Tags: cassandra

I have two node cassandra ring. On the one of the servers I am performing some bulk write operations - scanning a folder for the file list and writing list down to local Cassandra. There are about 500,000 files in there. I am putting 250 values in per one mutation.

Problem: I am getting **m.p.h.a.e.HUnavailableException** during the load. Moreover I have noticed strange thing on the other node. The load is significantly increased:

Before write operation:

```
me@10.1.18.55:~$ nodetool -h localhost ring
Address         DC          Rack        Status State   Load            Owns                Token
                                                                              85070591730234615865843651857942052864
10.1.18.51      datacenter1 rack1       Up     Normal  221.3 KB        50.00%              0
10.1.18.55      datacenter1 rack1       Up     Normal  185.65 KB       50.00%              85070591730234615865843651857942052864
```

After write operation

```
me@10.1.18.55:~$ nodetool -h localhost ring
Note: Ownership information does not include topology, please specify a keyspace. 
Address         DC          Rack        Status State   Load            Owns                Token                                       
                                                                                           85070591730234615865843651857942052864      
10.1.18.51      datacenter1 rack1       Up     Normal  124.44 MB       50.00%              0                                           
10.1.18.55      datacenter1 rack1       Up     Normal  303.39 KB       50.00%              85070591730234615865843651857942052864
```

Does it somehow crashing my load?

Cassandra version 1.1.0, consistency type Quorum.

Here is mutator implementation bit:

```
    mutator.addInsertion("items", columnFamily, HFactory.createColumn(
        i.getAndIncrement(), xml, LongSerializer.get(),
        StringSerializer.get()));
```

The data seams to be written into one big "items" row...

Comment: I found some posts about bulk loading into Cassandra http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/bulk-loading . Is this the only solution for my case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're modeling things as One Big Row, don't do that; the row is the unit of partitioning and replication, so you need (many) more rows than you have nodes in the ring, to get a good load distribution.

UnavailableException probably does mean you're overloading the cluster.  You can throttle your writes -- use "nodetool tpstats" to see how far behind it is -- or switch to the bulk loader that Dalius linked, which is designed to deal with this kind of situation.

Comment: I have updated with the mutator implementation. It seams the details being written into one big row... Thanks jbellis

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure that size of row partition should not exceed more than 100Mb.
You can check same using cfstats.

For Column Family below stats are important and value should be less than 100Mb. If more than limit, it will cause compaction overhead and nodes will be offline.

Compacted partition maximum bytes:   [value] 
Compacted partition mean bytes:  [value]